# Display Invalid Login Details message using MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I want is, I have written a function for Validating user login credentials on server side. So what I am not getting is, I want to prompt a message if user has entered a invalid credentials.

Below is the Code for Validation.

```
public ActionResult ValidateUser()
    {
        string strUsername = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["txtUsername"]);
        string strPassword = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["txtPassword"]);
        //  return   RedirectToAction("Assign","App");
        string strReturn = "";
        string strDbError = string.Empty;
        strUsername = strUsername.Trim();
        strPassword = strPassword.Trim();
        string strUserName = "";
        string strCurrentGroupName = "";
        int intCurrentGroupID = 0;
        string controller = "";
        string action = "";

        UserProviderClient ObjUMS = new UserProviderClient();
        bool result = ObjUMS.AuthenticateUser(strUsername, strPassword, out strDbError);

        Session["isUserAuthenticated"] = result;

        try
        {
            if (result == true)
            {
                Session["isUserOutsideINDomain"] = true;
                Session["OutsideINDomainUsername"] = strUsername;
                //redirect to respective controller

                UMS ObjUMSDATA = new UMS();
                //strUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
                strUserName = strUsername;
                _UMSUserName = strUserName;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserName))
                {
                    List<UMSGroupDetails> lstUMSGroupDetails = null;
                    List<UMSLocationDetails> lstUMSLocationDetails = null;

                    ObjUMSDATA.GetUMSGroups(strUserName, out strCurrentGroupName, out intCurrentGroupID, out lstUMSLocationDetails, out lstUMSGroupDetails);
                    if (strCurrentGroupName != "" && intCurrentGroupID != 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.LoginUserName = strUserName.ToUpper();
                        ViewBag.CurrentGroupName = strCurrentGroupName;
                        ViewBag.CurrentGroupID = intCurrentGroupID;
                        ViewBag.GroupDetails = lstUMSGroupDetails;
                        ViewBag.LocationDetails = lstUMSLocationDetails;
                        TempData["LoginUserName"] = strUserName.ToUpper();
                        Session["LoginUserName"] = strUsername.ToUpper();
                        TempData["Location"] = lstUMSLocationDetails;
                        Session["strCurrentGroupName"] = strCurrentGroupName;
                        TempData["strCurrentGroupName"] = strCurrentGroupName;
                        TempData.Keep();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Shared");
                        //action = "ErrorPage"; controller = "UnAutherized";      
                        TempData["strLoginErrorInfo"] = "Invalid Username or Password";
                        TempData.Keep();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (strCurrentGroupName == "SAP Executive")
            {
                action = "Assign"; controller = "App";
            }
            else if (strCurrentGroupName == "Maintenance Lead")
            {
                //return RedirectToAction("App", "Certify");
                action = "Certify"; controller = "App";
            }
            else if (strCurrentGroupName == "NEIQC CMM")
            {
                //return RedirectToAction("App", "Approver");
                action = "Approver"; controller = "App";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "ValidateUser", ex.Message);
        }
        return RedirectToActionPermanent(action, controller);
    }
```

Please suggest where I can prompt in my above code.

Comment: What do you mean by prompt here? If you want to send back a prompt you can do something like `return Json("Invalid Credentials", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` if you are using AJAX to post to your function. If you are using a model binding, you can use `ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid Credentials");
        return View(viewModel);`

Comment: @RahulSharma: Thanks for the comment,  can you post in an answer section. so it could be visible properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways in which you can send your message prompts back to the View from your Controller:

If you are using AJAX to POST to your Controller, you could use a JSON response. An example of this would be:

```
$.ajax({
 //You AJAX code....
 //On success
 success: function (data){
   if (data == "Invalid") {
     alert("Invalid Credentials Supplied");
  }
 },
 //If there is any error
 error: function (data) {
 alert("Could not process your request.");
 },
});
```

And in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult ValidateUser()
{
//Your logic
return Json("Invalid", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**OR**

You can use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` also to set your prompt messages. An example would be:

On your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var yourPrompt= '@ViewBag.PromptMessage';
        alert(yourPrompt);
    });
</script>
```

In your Controller, you can setup your prompt:

```
ViewBag.PromptMessage= "Invalid Credentials Supplied";
```

Alternatively using `ViewData` with a conditional statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var yourPrompt= '@ViewData["PromptMessage"]';
        if(yourPrompt=="Invalid"){
        alert("Invalid Credentials supplied");
       }        
    });
</script>
```

In your Controller, you can setup your prompt:

```
ViewData["PromptMessage"] = "Invalid";
```

**OR**

You could use ModelState to display your prompts or errors on your View. This is used when you are using a strongly typed Model-View binding in your Controller. An example:

In your View, setup your `ValidationSummary`:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

By default, ValidationSummary filters out field level error messages. The following will display error messages as a summary at the top. Please make sure that you don't have a ValidationMessageFor method for each of the fields in your model. These are for specific fields only.

You can also display a custom error message using ValidationSummary. To display a custom error message, first of all, you need to add custom errors into the ModelState in the appropriate action method.

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
  //Your condition where you want to show your message
  //Add to the model state, your custom error 
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Credentials Supplied")
  return View("Your View Name");
}
```

**Addition:**

If you want to customize the styling of your error message in your View, add a class to your ValidationSummary like this `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`. Then you can use this class in your CSS like this:

```
.text-danger
{ 
/*Your style*/
}
```

Comment: I tried the last one with my current above code, but it was not prompting the message which was suppied. any help

Comment: The `ModelState` one? Did you try the `ViewData` method?

Comment: No I didnt tried the viewdata. i added like this `else
                {                    
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Username and password supplied");
                }` but no prompt

Comment: Did you add `ValidationSummary` in your View? The last method is for strongly typed Model-View binding. I would suggest you to go with `ViewData` or `ViewBag` method

Comment: No, I didnt added that.. where to add that  part ? do u want to see my HTML part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190829/discussion-between-b-n-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your answer